# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in Node Javascript

Tags: java, node.js, jar

I am trying to execute a command using node JavaScript.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
   cmd  = spawn('java -cp C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\dom4j.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\poi-3.9-20121203.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.6.0.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\excelreader.jar astral.excelreader.Main 11 33 fsdds', []);
```

Then it is showing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

If I remove these two jars`(C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.6.0.jar;)` from command then it is not showing the above error. But I want some class files in that jars.

If I run the first command directly in windows command prompt(without using node js) then it will execute correcty.
Anybody know why that error comes if I add these following jars?
`C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.6.0.jar;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String `c:\windows\` in javascript should be like this:

```
c:\\windows\\
```

And spawn syntax: `spawn(command, [args], [options])`

```
spawn('java', ['-cp', 'c:\\java\\...'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to double the backslashes. Instead of

```
'java -cp C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\dom4j.jar;...'
```

write

```
'java -cp C:\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_45\\lib\\dom4j.jar;...'
```